# Multiple draggable column handles

Tags: javascript, html, draggable

New to javacsript and first time coding a web from scratch...

Hello all.
I'm trying to achieve draggable columns like this js fiddle I found here on stack:
    http://jsfiddle.net/T4St6/

I succeeded in making it work for my web: http://www.dariusou.com/ but am clueless about how to make multiple columns of that since the script targets the divs specifically (left,right):

```
var isResizing = false,
lastDownX = 0;

$(function () {
var container = $('#container'),
    left = $('#left'),
    right = $('#right'),
    handle = $('#handle');

handle.on('mousedown', function (e) {
    isResizing = true;
    lastDownX = e.clientX;
});

$(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
    // we don't want to do anything if we aren't resizing.
    if (!isResizing) 
        return;

    var offsetRight = container.width() - (e.clientX - container.offset().left);

    left.css('right', offsetRight);
    right.css('width', offsetRight);
}).on('mouseup', function (e) {
    // stop resizing
    isResizing = false;
});
});
```

Would this code be convenient to achieve what I want, or should I look for another code to work from? (I cant write scripts from scratch yet) What I'm trying to achieve is just this kind of draggable columns with handles, but multiple of them, like the image attached to this post.
[image]

Ideally I would also like to achieve a random drag position for each of these divs( on every load )in the future.(see attached)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you change your handle to a class:

```
<div id='handle' class="handle"></div>
```

Define your class behavior:

```
$('.handle').on('mousedown', function (e) {
     target = e.target.id; //store the id
     isResizing = true;
     lastDownX = e.clientX;
});
```

Add more div:

```
<div id="left2"> This is the left side's content! </div>
    <!-- Right side -->
    <div id="right2">
        <!-- Actual resize handle -->
        <div id='handle2' class="handle"></div> This is the right side's content!
    </div>
```

Resize depend on target handle:

```
if(target == 'handle'){
     left.css('right', offsetRight);
     right.css('width', offsetRight);
} else if(target == 'handle2'){
     left2.css('right', offsetRight);
     right2.css('width', offsetRight);
}
```

Check this fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/T4St6/292/](http://jsfiddle.net/T4St6/292/),there are many other ways to make it, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for this. I am trying this out now as we speak. Question - does this method allow me to add script to achieve the random on load sequence? i assume I would need to be able to target the handles separately

Comment: I'm also having difficulty trying to position them with height... this is caused by the position:absolute ... is there a way this can work without that? I want to stack them naturally and not position them one by one using  top: xx px all the way...is there a way for the divs to stack naturally inside the container?

Comment: $('#id') is select first element with that id, $('.class') is select all elements with that class then return an odered array. From what I understand, check this jsfiddle.net/T4St6/293 maybe it helps.

Comment: Wow this is exacly what i wanted... unfortunately this script surpasses my knowledge in coding.. could you be kind enough to explain what is happening in it? Also now that everything is defined by class i no longer have separated div ids? This is because I would need to put a slideshow in each of these divs and now the html only contains container div, I am confused now

Comment: Add a div outside left and right with position:relative; height: ??px; is fine.

Comment: yes, it was added after the javascript function "append". Use Ctrl+shift+c then click it to see the html in Developer tool.

Comment: ok actually there are many things i want to do that requires the divs to be separately styled... not to mention content too.. so the script needs to work like before but with the return ordered array –

Comment: ok i saw it starts with left0 right0. I tried replacing the codes except my css and I got it to work, except there is a stange space on top.. it seems that the top: xx px is applied to the first div, left0 and right0. how do I exclude that? also, when i add text to a div, (e.g right2) everything goes haywire...

Comment: ('top', 40*(i+1)) mean with i = 0, top = 40px, you can change to ('top', 40*i)

Comment: great it works!!!what about the text? for some reason when I want to target the divs (e.g right2) insdie container div, the whole code falls apart...

Comment: it seems to be caused by the script generating the random output values for the column width.handle position and also my own css styling of the divs

Comment: codeshare.io/zHoqJ , live notepad, you can show your code there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124997/discussion-between-da-hao-and-k-angel7).